# Swift - [Int] is not a subtype of @lvalue$T2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to do a simple sort function in a swift playground but I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <EXPR>:20:22: error: '[Int]' is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T2'
            swap(&a,k,j) //Here in &a
```

I have written the following code:

```
let arr:[Int] = [1,3,53,24,52,1,234,5,3]

func swap(inout a:[Int], num1:Int, num2:Int){
    var value = a[num1]
    a[num1] = a[num2]
    a[num2] = value
}

func sort(a:[Int]){
    var j = 0
    var k = 0
    for (k = j ; k<=a.count; k++){
        if(k != a.count){
            if(a[k] < a[j]){
                swap(&a,k,j)
            }
        }else{
            j++;
        }
    }
 }

print ("\(sort(arr)) is the array")
```

Any idea of why this does not work? Am I referencing the array incorrectly, thanks!

UPDATE:
As Martin R pointed out the errors, here is the corrected code:

```
var arr:[Int] = [1,3,53,24,52,1,234,5,3]
```

And the sort function:

```
func sort(inout a:[Int]) -> [Int]{
var j = 0
var k = 0
for (k = j ; k <= a.count; k++){
    if(k != a.count){
        if(a[k] < a[j]){
            swap(&a,j,k)
        }
    }else{
        j++;
        k = j
    }
}
    return a
}
```

Finally:

```
print ("\(sort(&arr)) is the array")
```

Comment: Your new sort() functions sorts the passed array *and* returns it. Usually you either sort the passed array and return nothing *or* leave the passed array unchanged and return a sorted array. In the second case you would not need an inout-parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local parameter `a` in

```
func sort(a:[Int])
```

is by default a *constant*. Since you want to modify the passed array, you have
to declare that parameter as `inout` in the same way as in the `swap()` function:

```
func sort(inout a:[Int])
```

Moreover, the passed array has to be *variable*:

```
var arr:[Int] = [1,3,53,24,52,1,234,5,3]
```

and you have to prefix it with the ampersand when it is passed as an argument
for an in-out parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function:

```
sort(&arr)
println(arr)
```

Note also that

```
print ("\(sort(arr)) is the array")
```

does not print the array result because `sort()` has no return value.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution, my array was specified as a constant (changed it to var) and, by passing its address, it worked and yes, I also added a return and also corrected the sort.

Comment: Right on, but to be pedantic: passing `&arr` doesn't pass the address of `arr` — it just wraps `arr` as an `inout` expression for use with an `inout` function parameter. There is no direct memory-address referencing in Swift.

Comment: @rickster: You are totally right, thanks. – I think there are cases where the address is taken, e.g. when passed as argument to an UnsafeMutablePointer parameter, but that does not apply here.

Comment: Right -- dealing with raw memory addresses is a (special case) *library* feature, not a core language feature. (And on the other hand, the super secret `inout` menu includes treats like being able to `swap` the values of computed properties -- definitely not a pointer thing.)